# To get a extra column for Total for the pivoted columns

Tags: sql-server

This is my table for which i used pivot function to get required output

```
SELECT *FROM ( SELECT 
t3.State_Name,left(datename(month,t1.Invoice_Date),3)as [month],t1.Qty
from t1 join t3 on t1.Area_code=t3.Area_code) as PIVOT
(
SUM(qty) 
FOR [month] IN ( apr, 
may, jun, jul, aug, sep))AS pvt
//for the above table my output is
State_Name  apr   may   jun  jul   aug     sep
--------- -----  ----- ----- ---- ----    -----
Andhra      7    NULL   NULL   6    12      16
Telangana   9     1      13   NULL  NULL    13
TN         NULL   4     NULL   6    10      19
```

I need one more column in this table which gives the total for the months
so i used the above table by inserting the above table into new..but i need the output without inserting into new table

```
select state_name,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,coalesce(apr,0) + coalesce(may,0) 
+ coalesce(jun,0) + coalesce(jul,0) + coalesce(aug,0) + coalesce(sep,0) as 
"total"from #temp8
//output 
state_name   apr    may  jun   jul   aug    sep     total
----------  -----  ---- ----  ----  -----  ----    ------
 Andhra       7    NULL  NULL   6    12     16       41
Telangana     9     1    13    NULL NULL    13       36
  TN        NULL    4    NULL   6    10     19       39
```

Sample data

```
2017-06-12   100           Telangana           
2017-07-18   101           Andhra              
2017-06-16   102           Telangana           
2017-04-24   103           Andhra              
2017-02-23   104           Andhra              
2017-03-17   105           Andhra              
2017-05-08   106           Telangana           
2017-04-01   107           Telangana           
2017-05-29   108           TN                  
2017-07-19   109           TN                  
2017-08-17   110           TN                  
2017-08-13   111           TN                  
2017-09-12   112           TN                  
2017-09-02   113           TN                  
2017-10-13   114           Andhra              
2017-08-11   115           Andhra              
2017-09-13   116           Telangana           
2017-10-10   117           Telangana               
2017-10-13   118           Telangana           
2017-11-06   119           TN                  
2017-09-18   120           Andhra              
2017-09-11   115           Andhra
```

Comment: Why can't you merge the two queries into one, without inserting into new table? Just replace `SELECT *FROM ( SELECT ` with `SELECT state_name,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,coalesce(apr,0) + coalesce(may,0) 
+ coalesce(jun,0) + coalesce(jul,0) + coalesce(aug,0) + coalesce(sep,0) as 
"total" FROM ( SELECT `

Answer (score 0):

Having your sample data:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [DateAdded] DATE
   ,[value] INT
   ,[name] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([DateAdded], [value], [name])
VALUES   ('2017-06-12', '100', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-07-18', '101', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-06-16', '102', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-04-24', '103', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-02-23', '104', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-03-17', '105', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-05-08', '106', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-04-01', '107', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-05-29', '108', 'TN')
        ,('2017-07-19', '109', 'TN')
        ,('2017-08-17', '110', 'TN')
        ,('2017-08-13', '111', 'TN')
        ,('2017-09-12', '112', 'TN')
        ,('2017-09-02', '113', 'TN')
        ,('2017-10-13', '114', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-08-11', '115', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-09-13', '116', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-10-10', '117', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-10-13', '118', 'Telangana')
        ,('2017-11-06', '119', 'TN')
        ,('2017-09-18', '120', 'Andhra')
        ,('2017-09-11', '115', 'Andhra');

SELECT [name]
      ,[Apr], [Aug], [Feb], [Jul], [Mar], [Oct], [Sep], [Jun], [May], [Nov]
      ,[Total]
FROM
(
    SELECT [name]
          ,COALESCE(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, [DateAdded]), 3), 'Total') AS [Month]
          ,SUM([value]) [value]
    FROM @DataSource
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS
    (
        ([name], DATENAME(MONTH, [DateAdded]))
       ,[name]
    )
) PVT
PIVOT
(
    SUM([value]) FOR [Month] IN ([Apr], [Aug], [Feb], [Jul], [Mar], [Oct], [Sep], [Total], [Jun], [May], [Nov])
) PVT;
```

The query gives us:

[image]